# Style Filemaker portal scroll bars in new theme

Tags: themes, filemaker

I'm making a new theme in Filemaker 18 by modifying an existing one. Most things are fine, once I'd understood Filemaker's idiosyncratic approach to styling.

However, I can't find a way to style the scroll bars on a portal – the top and bottom arrows and the body of the bar. There just doesn't seem to be anywhere that I can change their attributes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, these are the only attributes of a portal that you can select: https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help%2Fformatting-portals.html%23ww1281567

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. It's infuriating that the developers have chosen to make small things like this uneditable.

Is there any way I can alter the css directly? I can't even find where my custom theme is stored.

Comment: I believe it is stored within the .fmp12 file itself (and therefore cannot be accessed directly).

Comment: Sigh. Thanks for your time taking me through this.